# Tricking the taskbar into thinking a separate launcher program is the same as the program it launches?

Tags: windows, shortcuts, launcher

A program I use (not developed nor maintained by me) uses a ribbon. The ribbon isn't organized as well as it could be, but luckily by editing the ribbon.xml file in the program's installation folder, I can tweak it so it's easier to work with (I've already gotten the go-ahead from the software developers to tweak it).

Unfortunately, the way the program updates is a little odd. When it installs, it creates a folder named "version-versionGUID". When it updates, it deletes the current installation and replaces it with a folder named "version-newversionGUID" This causes two problems for me: 1) I can't create a permanent shortcut to the program since its file path changes every time the program updates and 2) Every time the program updates my ribbon.xml changes are overwritten.

To make that less painful, I created a VBS script that searches the directory where the version-versionGUID folders are created and once I find the program's installation folder I can launch the executable. Problem 1 solved -- running the script will always launch the latest version of the program. Before doing that though, the script deletes the ribbon.xml file in the program's directory and clones in a modified version with my desired edits. Problem 2 solved -- I pinned a shortcut to the taskbar that launched wscript.exe "launcher.vbs", changed its icon to the program's icon, and then all's good, right?

I would call it a day, but there's one small problem. When the program is run, instead of the program taking over the pinned taskbar icon like a pinned program normally does, a new taskbar item is created, and now I have two items on the taskbar (launcher icon and program) when normally I'd only have just the program. This, obviously, is because the launcher isn't actually the program so of course it's not going to be taken over. Still, I'd like to trick Windows into thinking this launcher is the program so that it gets taken over.

So, my question is twofold:

1) Is there any way I can trick/force Windows into having the program take over the launcher's icon in the taskbar, and then restoring the launcher when the program is closed?

2) If not, is there a way to control where the new program is placed on the taskbar when it's opened (I'd like to place it next to the launcher), disable the launcher icon in the taskbar when the program is run, and then re-enable the launcher when the program is closed, all without restarting explorer.exe?

For both 1 & 2, I'm fine venturing out of VBScript -- the only reason it was used was because it was easy to use and the result is lightweight. In fact, I'd prefer to venture outside VBScript because AFAIK it's not powerful enough for me to implement auto-updating when I run the launcher so that I don't have to manually update the program.

Comment: Get the software developers to roll out your fixes.

Comment: It's a personal preference regarding the ribbon. They like ginormous buttons and to keep the default ribbon clunky with only half of the bar filled up on each tab and duplicate buttons across multiple tabs to make it "new user friendly". The "power user design [I] use is not friendly enough to new users" and isn't going to be considered for the official layout.